# Trying to show 3 maps at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to show 3 heatmaps as the same time, the page loads but instead of maps they are three grey rectangles. This is how I create and try to show the heatmaps:

**Javascript**

```
    function search_around(){
        $.mobile.loading( "show", { text: 'Retrieving information ...', textVisible: true });

        var dir = document.getElementById('address').value;
        var radio = document.getElementById('radio').value;
        if (radio>1000) {
            radio = 1000;
        } else if (radio==0) {
            radio = 500
        }
        var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geo.geocode({'address':dir}, function(results, status){
            if (status=='OK'){
                var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
                return $.getJSON('{{ url_for('search_around') }}', {'email':$.cookie('login_email'), 'lat': loc['lat'], 'lon':loc['lng'], 'radio':radio}).done(function(data){
                    $.mobile.loading( "hide" );

                    result = data['result'];
                    var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc['lat'],loc['lng'])
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 13,
                        center: centerlatlng,
                        styles: [
                        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
                        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
                        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
                        {featureType: 'administrative.locality',elementType:'labels.text.fill',stylers:[{color: '#d59563'}]},
                        {featureType: 'poi', elementType: 'labels.text.fill',stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]},
                        {featureType: 'poi.park', elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]},
                        {featureType: 'poi.park', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]},
                        {featureType: 'road', elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]},
                        {featureType: 'road', elementType: 'geometry.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]},
                        {featureType: 'road', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]},
                        {featureType: 'road.highway', elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
                        {featureType: 'road.highway', elementType: 'geometry.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]},
                        {featureType: 'road.highway', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]},
                        {featureType: 'transit', elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]},
                        {featureType: 'transit.station', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]},
                        {featureType: 'water', elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]},
                        {featureType: 'water', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]},
                        {featureType: 'water', elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]}
                        ]
                    };

                    var map_acc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_search_acc'), myOptions);
                    var map_cons = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_search_cons'), myOptions);
                    var map_emis = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_search_emis'), myOptions);

                    var heatmap_points_acc = []
                    var heatmap_points_cons = []
                    var heatmap_points_emis = []

                    acc_points = result['acc_latlon'].split('#')
                    $.each(acc_points,function(i, text){
                        if (text.length > 3) {
                            lat_lon = text.split(',');
                            heatmap_points_acc.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lon[0], lat_lon[1]))
                        }
                    });
                    var pointArray_acc = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmap_points_acc);
                    var heatmap_acc = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                        data: pointArray_acc
                    });
                    heatmap_acc.set('threshold', 10);
                    heatmap_acc.set('radius', 10);
                    heatmap_acc.set('opacity', 0.8000);
                    heatmap_acc.set('dissipating', true);
                    heatmap_acc.setMap(map_acc);

                    $('#map_search_acc').css("height","500px");
                    $('#map_search_acc').css("width","100%");
                    $('#map_search_acc').redraw();

                    cons_points = result['cons_latlon'].split('#')
                    $.each(cons_points,function(i, text){
                        if (text.length > 3) {
                            lat_lon = text.split(',');
                            heatmap_points_cons.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lon[0], lat_lon[1]))
                        }
                    });
                    var pointArray_cons = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmap_points_cons);
                    var heatmap_cons = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                        data: pointArray_cons
                    });
                    heatmap_cons.set('threshold', 10);
                    heatmap_cons.set('radius', 10);
                    heatmap_cons.set('opacity', 0.8000);
                    heatmap_cons.set('dissipating', true);
                    heatmap_cons.setMap(map_cons);

                    $('#map_search_cons').css("height","500px");
                    $('#map_search_cons').css("width","100%");
                    $('#map_search_cons').redraw();

                    emis_points = result['emis_latlon'].split('#')
                    $.each(emis_points,function(i, text){
                        if (text.length > 3) {
                            lat_lon = text.split(',');
                            heatmap_points_emis.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lon[0], lat_lon[1]))
                        }
                    });
                    var pointArray_emis = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmap_points_emis);
                    var heatmap_emis = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                        data: pointArray_emis
                    });
                    heatmap_emis.set('threshold', 10);
                    heatmap_emis.set('radius', 10);
                    heatmap_emis.set('opacity', 0.8000);
                    heatmap_emis.set('dissipating', true);
                    heatmap_emis.setMap(map_emis);

                    $('#map_search_emis').css("height","500px");
                    $('#map_search_emis').css("width","100%");
                    $('#map_search_emis').redraw();

                }).fail(function(){
                    show_message_error_connection();
                });
            } else {
                alert('Address couldn\'t be found in google Geocoder service');
                $.mobile.loading("hide");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Html**

```
<div data-role="page" id = "page_search" >
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1><center><img href='#page_test' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/pxs_title.png')}}" style="height:25px;"></center></h1>
            <a href="#panel_left" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-grid"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="panel">
            <center>
            <label for="text-basic"> <font size="5">Address</font> </label>
            <input id="address" type="textbox" size="40">
            <label for="text-basic" ><font size="5">Ratio (1000m - 500m):</font></label>
            <input id="radio" type="textbox" size="20" value="500">
            <input id="search" type="button" value="SEARCH" onclick="javascript:search_around();">
            </center>
        </div>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" id = "list-search-maps">
            <li data-role="list-divider"><b>Map Accelerations</b></li>
            <div id="map_search_acc" style="width:750; height:700"></div>
            <li data-role="list-divider"><b>Map Consumption</b></li>
            <div id="map_search_cons" style="width:750; height:700"> </div>
            <li data-role="list-divider"><b>Map Emissions</b></li>
            <div id="map_search_emis" style="width:750; height:700"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I've used this same process to create 1 heatmap and it works, same exact process, what is it not right now? I've already checked that I receive the query in my backend and the front is receiving the data back, but it doesn't show it in the maps. I'm pretty new to html+javascript so I'm lost right now and I don't know what to try

Comment: Try to create a JSFiddle, it is hard to help this way, too much code. Try to isolate the issue.

Comment: I've never used JSFIddle, and I really don't know how to use it, anyway, I've tried to create it: https://jsfiddle.net/5ppL5or8/1/ I'm not receiving any requests in the backend, so I changed it to try to create each map with 1 single point. The lat,lon input know should stablish the center point of each map

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console when you see the 3 grey rectangles instead of the three maps?

Comment: Nothing at all. It displays the rest of the page properly and 3 gray rectangles instead of the maps

Comment: I've checked with postman and the backend is sending the data for all 3 maps right

Comment: I've changed to design to use only 1 map and change it every time by using 3 tabs. I've tried to create another JSFiddle but I really don't understand how to do it because I don't receive the requests in the backend: https://jsfiddle.net/j9e9501o/

Answer (score 0):

As usual, when you are 100% sure that something it is not the problem, just take a look at it ... This is what I did, and the problem was in:

```
var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc['lat'],loc['lng'])
```

I don't know why both values were sent properly to the backend but they were read to create centerlatlng as "function (){return a}" and "function (){return b}", so the centerpoint of the map was (Null, Null) and that's why the maps (now map) weren't displayed. It has taken a lot of time (I've learn a lot in the process) but I could find the answer, I send back from the backend the lat and long coordinates and problem solved:

```
var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data['lat'],data['lon']);
```